# Mysql select dynamic row values as column name from a table and value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have arranged a survey where a project has some questions. Users have to collect the given project answer from public. Survey tables like

user tables

```
user_id     user_name
  1          User 1   
  2          User 2
```

Project table

```
project_id  project_name
  1           project 1    
  2           project 2
```

Question table

```
ques_id  project_id  ques_name
  1         1         Question 1
  2         1         Question 2 
  3         1         Question 3
  4         1         Question 4
```

Answer table

```
ans_id  public_id  user_id ques_id  ques_ans
  1         1      1         1     Answer 1
  2         1      1         2     Answer 2 
  3         1      1         3     Answer 3
  4         1      1         4     Answer 4
```

Now i want to generate a reports where question table values as column name matched by given project_id and question answers as value from answer table matched by ques_id

And, her is my expected output:

```
User_Name  public_id  Question 1  Question 2  Question 3  ...
User 1        1         Answer 1   Answer 2    Answer 3   ...
```

Someone suggested to use pivot but i found "MySQL doesn't have native support for pivoting operations" can anyone help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: On the assumption that each user can answer each question only once, answer_id serves no purpose

Comment: That aside, ignore the suggested duplicate and instead consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the code is working

```
SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
    'MAX(IF(a.ques_id = ',
    ques_id,
    ', a.ques_ans, NULL)) AS `',
    ques_name,'`'
    )
    ) INTO @sql
     FROM survey_answer inner join survey_question on  survey_answer.ques_id=survey_question.id;

set @sql = CONCAT('select u.user_name ,q.category_id,a.p_code, ' ,@sql,'  FROM `survey_answer` as a
LEFT JOIN `users` as u ON a.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN `survey_question` as q ON a.ques_id= q.id');
 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use another output format of the query. For example:

```
SELECT user_name, answer.project_id, ques_name, ques_ans
FROM 
    `answer` 
    INNER JOIN `user` USING (user_id)
    INNER JOIN `question` USING (ques_id);
```

To restrict rows by specific project add `WHERE` clause:

```
 WHERE project_id = @ProjectID
```

Then **transform the result to the desired view using PHP**.
If it is critical to solve the question using MySQL then create new colums manually using aliaces. To aggregate rows by user and project use `GROUP BY` clause. To show the possible non-empty values use `MAX()` function. In your case:

```
SELECT
  user_name, project_id,
  MAX(IF(ques_name = 'Question 1', ques_ans, NULL)) AS `Question 1`,
  MAX(IF(ques_name = 'Question 2', ques_ans, NULL)) AS `Question 2`,
  MAX(IF(ques_name = 'Question 3', ques_ans, NULL)) AS `Question 3`,
  MAX(IF(ques_name = 'Question 4', ques_ans, NULL)) AS `Question 4`
FROM
    (SELECT 
        ans_id, user_id, user_name, answer.project_id, ques_name, ques_ans
    FROM 
        answer
        INNER JOIN `user` USING (user_id)
        INNER JOIN question USING (ques_id)
        ) AS tmp
GROUP BY
  user_id, project_id;
```

Comment: @RiyadhAhmed,  my answer is a "plan B".

Comment: plan B? actually i am still trying to transform the result by following the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns) but cannot get working...

Comment: @Riyadh Ahmed, you are right. If it is critical to solve the question using MySQL then you could try to adapt [existing solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns) for your case. Otherwise use "plan B".

Comment: @ Alexander i have tried that existing solution but failed.Can you please help me how can i transform the result or use existing solution to solve?

Comment: @Riyadh Ahmed, you are persistent :) See new version of my answer.

Comment: sorry for late. i solved the query but facing a problem to run the query using codeigniter. how can i execute the prepare stmt?

Answer (score 0):

your query should be :

```
SELECT an.user_name,an.public_id,qs.quest_name,an.quest_answer 
FROM answer_table an,question_table qs,user_table usr
WHERE an.quest_id = qs.quest_id
AND an.user_id=usr.user_id
```

**For the table rotation** : here a similar question about rotating tables

[mysql pivot table date (vertical to horizontal data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715011/mysql-pivot-table-date-vertical-to-horizontal-data)