# mysql Script. Syntax error, Unexpected IDENT_QUOTED errors message on keyword PIVOT

Tags: mysql, pivot

I'm trying to open a script in my workbench but the keyword PIVOT is being underlined in red with an error message saying : ` Syntax error, Unexpected IDENT_QUOTED. 
Script:

```
select * from 
(select c1.id, a.num0,a.num1 from table1 c1
Inner Join
(select c2.id, if(team=1,1,0) as num0, if(team=2,1,0)as num1 from table1 c2,table2 r2
where c2.q_id = 2046 and r2.q_id = 2046 group by c2.d)a on a.id = c1.id) pvt

PIVOT(
For content
IN([team1],[team2]))pvt2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not have a PIVOT function. However, this functionality can be replicated using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression.

Based on your original query, it looks like you will need something similar to this:

```
select t2.id,
  sum(case when team = 1 then 1 else 0 end) num0,
  sum(case when team = 2 then 1 else 0 end) num1
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
  on t1.q_id = t2.q_id
group by t2.id
```

Comment: @user2210819 When you are pivoting data, typically you will use an aggregate function. You can also perform the same task using multiple joins on the table.

Comment: I should explain it clearly, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754867/sql-transform-fields-to-column)

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a syntax error because MySQL does not support `PIVOT`. You need to do some extra stuff to achieve what you want in MySQL. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) related question.