# Mysql Pivot/crosstab Query using JOIN query

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have **3 tables**, and I want to join all 3 table using pivot/crosstab.
Let me give you structure of table.

1. Table name : **wp_frm_item**

   ```
   id        post_id     user_id      name  

   121       19241          3          balaji

   120       19239          3          bajaj 

   119       19235          3          pressur Cooker
   ```
2. Table name : **wp_postmeta**

   ```
     post_id        meta_key       meta_value 

       19241          Price:         590

       19241          Shipping:       20

       19241          Size:           250X20

       19239          price          8412

       19239          Shipping:       20
   ```
3. Table Name : **wp_frm_item_meta**

   ```
       item_id        field_id       meta_value 

       121             96            happy

       121             388            a:3

       121             237           sell 

       120             96            no I'm sad

       120             388           a:4

       120             237           swap
   ```

   **And I want Output exactly like below:**

   ```
   post_id   item_id  user_id  name   price   shipping  size     96       388   237  


   19241     121      3       balaji   590     20       250X20  happy   a:3    sell
   ```

   Please help to execute query for this and thank you so much in advanced to read my post .

Comment: There are many answers showing how to pivot MySQL tables. What is different about your question so you can't use one of those answers?

Comment: yes dear I know there are number of answers available here but I'm still stuck at join with other table. If you have link available for same question please paste here, it might help to me

Comment: Here's a similar one I answered a couple of days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623866/join-tables-listing-rows-as-columns-joined-to-another-table/20626119#20626119

Comment: Thank you very very much. Your post gives me a lot help to build query and even my problem is also solve.Thank you so much

Comment: Still struggling? Consider providing proper DDLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help Barmar.

Solution  is here.

```
SELECT i.post_id,
       i.name post_name,
       i.user_id,
       MAX(IF(p.meta_key = "Shipping:",p.meta_value, NULL)) shipping,
       MAX(IF(p.meta_key = "Price:", p.meta_value, NULL)) price,
       MAX(IF(p.meta_key = "Size:", p.meta_value, NULL)) size,
       MAX(IF(p.meta_key = "_wp_attached_file", p.meta_value, NULL)) wp_attached_file
FROM wp_frm_items i
JOIN wp_postmeta p ON i.post_id = p.post_id 
where i.post_id  = 19241 
GROUP BY i.post_id
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02838/8)

Comment: Note that CASE conforms to the SQL standard