# sql query to get the column data in one row

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have below data in a table called data_tab

```
sn  code
2   101
2    
2   202
5   103
5   
5
```

How can i query to see result in one row, like

```
sn  code1  code2   code3
2   101            202
5   103
```

Comment: don't have time to write the exact query but this should get you on the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: Are you talking about `mysql` or `mssql`? Because you have one tab, but in question you telling about different

Answer (score 0):

Hi This gives the intented output ... take a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0dee8/13)

```
select sn,
        max(decode(rn,1,code)) as CODE_1
       ,max(decode(rn,2,code)) as CODE_2
       ,max(decode(rn,3,code)) as CODE_3

from
(
select sn,
      code,
      row_number() over (partition by sn order by null ) rn
from test
  )

group by sn
```