# MySQL - SELECT. Append field multiple times in row

Tags: mysql

Let's say that I have this table:

```
+-----------+-------+
| name      | seat  |
+-----------+-------+
| Andrew    | 1     |
| Andrew    | 5     |
| Andrew    | 15    |
| Billy     | 2     |
| Billy     | 5     |
+-----------+-------+
```

Is there any way for every `name`, to `SELECT` the corresponding occurrences of `seat` and append them in a single row?

Desired output:

```
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
| name      | seat1 | seat2 | seat3 |
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
| Andrew    | 1     | 5     | 15    |
| Billy     | 2     | 5     | NULL  |
+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I tried a simple `SELECT` with `GROUP`:

```
SELECT `name`, seat
FROM users
GROUP BY `name`
ORDER BY `name`;
```

But it of course outputs 1 column `seat` for every name.

```
+-----------+-------+
| name      | seat  |
+-----------+-------+
| Andrew    | 1     |
| Billy     | 2     |
+-----------+-------+
```

Is that even possible and how?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, it's called pivoting your results.  MySql doesn't support the pivot statement, so you'll need to use a prepared statement.  Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: Generally, it's best to handle display logic in the presentation layer - assuming you have that

Comment: @sgeddes Thanks for this info, I didn't know it was called that way. I always say that using the right keywords can get you the right information. The problem is knowing what they are :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using *group by*

you need *aggregate* funcion

group_concat is the one you might have to use,

```
  select name, group_concat(seat, SEPARATOR ",") from ...
```

it should produce something like

```
  +-----------+-------+
  | name      | seats |
  +-----------+-------+
  | Andrew    | 1,5,15|
  | Billy     | 2,5   |
  +-----------+-------+
```

sure it is a single column with all the strings in it separated by SEPARATOR string not multiple columns, but hopefully that will be useful/usable

otherwise you may have to then do some more string manipulation to use include the group_concat(seat, SEPARATOR ",") multiple times and parse the positions from it somehow, e.g.

```
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(seat, SEPARATOR ","), ",",1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(seat, SEPARATOR ","), ",",2), SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(seat, SEPARATOR ","), ",",3) from ....
```

of course that is also not precisely what you set out to get - I don't see how the number of columns selected can be made dynamic

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

hope this helps

Comment: It can be made dynamic. It's covered elsewhere - but it's a bit tedious

Comment: Yes it helps a lot. I didn't even think that the fields could be concatenated in one. Inspired by you, I tried a bit more complex stuff like `GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( column1, ' some string ', column2 ) SEPARATOR '<br/>' )` and it suited me great.