# convert column into rows based on another column

Tags: mysql

I have a below table that I like to convert the second column into rows based on first column.please see below screenshots.

Base Table:

[image]

Output Table:

[image]

Since I don't know the total rows of the columns so it is needed  to apply  dynamic sql. I can't figure it . can anyone please help me that would be very much appreciated.

Thanks
Arfater

Comment: If you have access to a presentation layer (e.g. PHP), it's best to do this kind of thing there. Otherwise this is a pivot query. Just search for 'mysql  pivot prepared statement' and (possibly) 'stored procedure'

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns)