# Join three table with dynamic columns and dynamic where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ddf14/4). 
Here, i need to find
No. of items (fetching item_name from 'item_list'),
ordered (fetching ordered_qty of 'order_detail'),
in each year (fetching ordered_date of 'orders').
Thus my output needs to be something like

```
year  red  blue yellow green
2010  20    20   20    10
2011  30    20   10    0
2012  20    10    0    0
2013  10    10    0    0
2014  20    10   10    10
```

where my column name will be list of items (if i add one more item to items_list that will be my 6th column but its values will be zero under it). I tried with subquery..

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: couldn't get it... :(