# How to dynamically create a view of all the field values related to an id in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is an example table:

```
--|--id--|--value--|
--|  1   |   v1    |
--|  1   |   v2    |
--|  1   |   v3    |
--|  1   |   v4    |
--|  2   |   v1    |
--|  2   |   v2    |
--|  2   |   v3    |
--|  3   |   v1    |
--|  3   |   v2    |
--------------------
```

The result of my query should be something like:

```
--|--id--|--value1-|--value2-|--value3-|--value4-|
--|  1   |   v1    |   v2    |   v3    |   v4    |
--|  2   |   v1    |   v2    |   v3    |   NULL  |
--|  3   |   v1    |   v2    |   NULL  |   NULL  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Is this possible using SQL?

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to [pivot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) your results.

Comment: Another example of pivoting: [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns). Did you do a search before asking the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use `conditional Aggregate`

```
SELECT id,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN value = 'v1' THEN Value
           END) Value1,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN value = 'v2' THEN Value
           END) Value2,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN value = 'v3' THEN Value
           END) Value3,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN value = 'v4' THEN Value
           END) Value4
FROM   yourtable
```