# Mysql dynamic rows to columns

Tags: php, mysql

layout

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fu81cqsl25vksd/layout.png?dl=0

link to image

**Example:**

Create Statement:

```
create table rating
(
  id int,
  tieid int,
  inspected datetime,
  rate varchar(50)
);
```

Insert Statement:

```
insert into rating values
(1,1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'E'),
(2,1, '2015-03-31 01:01:22', 'G'),
(3,1, '2015-02-26 01:01:22', 'B'),
(4,2, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'E'),
(5,2, '2015-03-31 01:01:22', 'F');
```

What Im trying to do is get an ouput with this data like such
cant seem to figure out how to get the query correct for this

tieid | inspected1 | rate1| inspected2 | rate2| inspected3 | rate3|
1     | 0000-00-00 |E       |2015-02-26  |B         | 2015-03-31  |G      |
2     | 0000-00-00 |E       |2015-03-31  |F        |                              |             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I would say the table design is not good if this is the expected output. You may want to consider sub-queries, but they would be fragile if more inspections were added.

Comment: is tieid a reference to another object in the same rating table? I don't understand your goal here, I don't even understand the relation between your expected result and your create table/values.

Comment: just added a photo of actual layout

Comment: what im trying to do is make a pivot table with all the ratings for each tie

Comment: jay, is there a better way to structure the layout. I need to keep the history of every inspection.

Comment: doesnt `select * from ratings where tieid=$d` do something... close to that? Edit: ok i think i get it, but if i'm right you're trying to group by tieid, while still selecting each individual row but turning those rows per tie into columns. I'm afraid this is not possible, still thinking a bit though.

Comment: i guess what im asking is how to set up a procedural call correctly for this

Comment: to make it pivot dynamically

Answer (score 0):

doing this in a single query, is not really possible in MySQL, because mySQL does not have anything to feature something like that.

on this page there's a suggestion that this might be doable using prepared statements, and dynamic query generations: [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns)

In my opinion, this approach is pretty WTFey and personally I would not use it and take a multiple query approach instead.

Comment: how would you suggest breaking this up into multiple queries?