# Multiple group by and count the grouped rows using mysql

Tags: mysql

I was having problems in creating counting rows by grouping based on a given field value.
For example: I have a data structure like this:

```
+------+------------+
| id   | channel    |
+------+------------+
| 1    | "facebook" |
| 2    | "twitter"  |
| 3    | "facebook" |
| 2    | "facebook" |
| 4    | "twitter"  |
| 5    | "facebook" |
| 2    | "twitter"  |
| 1    | "facebook" |
| 2    | "twitter"  |
+------------+------+
```

And I need this, we already know the category, they will be static i.e."facebook" and "twitter":

```
+------+------------+------------+---------+
| id   | Facebook   |   Twitter  |  Total  |
+------+------------+------------+---------+
| 1    |     2      |      0     |    2    |
| 2    |     1      |      3     |    4    |
| 3    |     1      |      0     |    1    |
| 4    |     0      |      1     |    1    |
| 5    |     1      |      0     |    1    |
+------+------------+------------+---------+
```

sqlfiddle link: [here is the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a6f1/4)

May not be the most elegant of answers but managed to come up with:

```
select user_id,user_name,
  count(case when channel = "twitter" then channel end) Twitter,
  count(case when channel = "facebook" then channel end) Facebook,
  count(case when channel in ("twitter","facebook") then channel end) Total
from april
group by user_id order by Total desc
```

If there improvements please, do answer or comment.

Comment: This looks like a standard solution. A modest performance benefit can usually be achieved by switching to the multiple LEFT JOIN approach, but I think what you've got looks neater. That said, this kind of issue (of data display) should really be handled in your application level code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select user_id,user_name,
  count(case when channel = "twitter" then channel end) Twitter,
  count(case when channel = "facebook" then channel end) Facebook,
  count(case when channel in ("twitter","facebook") then channel end) Total
from april
group by user_id order by Total desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi i think you should use SUM(CASE statement). Here how that's could lock like:

```
SELECT id, SUM(CASE WHEN channel = 'facebook' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as facebook,
       SUM(CASE WHEN channel = 'twitter' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as twitter
FROM `data`
GROUP BY id
```

[Here is SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a6f1/30) for that

Comment: @Aleksander , ya i have already implemeted that, if you look at the update. Was looking for a more efficient answer, since there are a lot of counts and comaprison involved

Comment: Oh sry didn't see that you edit question and add that... That's the first think that's crossed my mind for this problem... If I come with better idea I'll let you know :) GL

Answer (score -1):

Pivots in mysql...
Take a look on these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12599372/357403
- http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

Based on your fiddle (kudos for setting up that:-)):

```
SELECT  
  id,  
  COUNT(if(channel = "facebook", 1, NULL)) AS facebook, 
  COUNT(if(channel = "twitter", 1, NULL)) AS twitter, 
  COUNT(if(channel = "isntagram", 1, NULL)) AS instagram, 
  COUNT(if(channel = "microsite", 1, NULL)) AS microsite, 
  COUNT(if(channel = "kiosk", 1, NULL)) AS kiosk, 
  COUNT(*) As Total
FROM data 
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: I don't know if pivotal is able to solve my problem here, as I need to count according to channel, and the channels are fixed and not dynamic.

Comment: @Koshinae, yes I understand the usage, but in my problem I need to count the grouped rows as well and fortunately the channel will that will appear in the rows are limited and known first hand.

Comment: @mane, nah, no worries, just there are people who come by, doesn't understand the answer, does a -1, then goes away forever :-)