# Creating view for Mysql data presented in horizontal way

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

Sorry for an unclear topic but i am not sure how to better describe my situation here

I have a table similar to this:

[image: Test Table]

And i was asked to create a view based on the table with some requirements, and the out come should be something like:

[image]

(I hard code this table to show my expected result for the View)

I am quite new to Create View Function and i've tried to look for solution online but i can't find much useful information.

Comment: You want to _pivot_ the result from the query

Comment: The CREATE VIEW itself is no issue, solve its SELECT and you're there!

Comment: Will it always be A, B, C and D - or will more device types show up later?

Comment: @K.Leung , this questions has an already answered here ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287118/transform-vertical-table-to-horizontal-with-mysql

Comment: @jarlh, more device will be show up later

Comment: The accepted answer will not return those new devices.

Comment: is there anyway to create a view that can show future new devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for creating a view is really simple:

```
create view <view name> as
    <select query here>;
```

The question that you have asked is for a view that returns exactly five columns.  You can handle this with an aggregation query:

```
create view v_name as
    select device_id,
           sum(case when device_type = 'A' then count else 0 end) as a,
           sum(case when device_type = 'B' then count else 0 end) as b,
           sum(case when device_type = 'C' then count else 0 end) as c,
           sum(case when device_type = 'D' then count else 0 end) as d
    from t  -- your table name here
    group by device_id;
```

The caveat is that this returns exactly the types that are in the `SELECT` -- no others if they are in the table.  If you need flexible columns, then you have a problem.  It is not hard to construct a dynamic query to return the values at any given time.  However, you cannot put dynamic SQL in a view.  If this is something you need, then some alternative mechanism -- such as JSON -- might be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helps a lot! does that mean if there are more device that would need JSON to do so?

Comment: @K.Leung . . . No.  If you do not know the complete list, then JSON may be helpful.