# How to loop a condition dynamically within a single select query in MySql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, pivot-table, group-concat, crosstab

I am trying to implement a Pivot Table (Cross Tab query) for showing attendance details of an employee.
I managed this by following query.

```
SELECT id,name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(if(date = '2015-04-01', atten, NULL)) AS '2015-04-01',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(date = '2015-04-02', atten, NULL)) AS '2015-04-02',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(date = '2015-04-03', atten, NULL)) AS '2015-04-03',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(date = '2015-04-04', atten, NULL)) AS '2015-04-04',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(date = '2015-04-05', atten, NULL)) AS '2015-04-05'
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id;
```

I used this code in my procedure, now i don't want to write group_concat multiple times, and it is dynamic, and changes every time.

So I want to loop group_concat , if possible.

Please See this -
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b30e2/1

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: Query is generated , but not the full query. Please see - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b30e2/3

Comment: Thanx Man. after doing some changes according to your link. It works fine. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b30e2/18

Comment: I provide the looping code to generate the `SELECT` in [my pivot blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot).