# How to make one column in to more colums

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a really complicated SQL question for a mySQL database.
I will first introduce all needed tables for this question:

User Table:

```
Id  date_created
------------------------------
1   2015-09-19T14:18:07.000Z 
2   2015-09-20T01:16:34.000Z
3   2015-09-21T15:10:21.000Z
…
```

Setting table:

```
Id  User_id     setting_key     setting_value
----------------------------------------------
1   1           city            1
2   3           city            2
3   2           city            1
…
```

City names Table:

```
Id  name
------------------
1   New York    
2   Los Angeles
3   Boston
…
```

With a select-query I Would like to achieve this:

```
date            New York    Los Angeles     Boston  …
------------------------------------------------------
2015-09-19      1           0               0   
2015-09-20      2           0               0
2015-09-21      2           1               0
…
```

For every date in certain range how many users has as setting New york, Los, Angeles....
The only thing I can achieve is this query:

```
select date(u.date_created), n.name, count(u.id)
from user u inner join setting s
    on u.id = s.user_id
    and setting_key = 'city'
    inner join name n
    on s.setting_value = n.id
where u.date_created > '2015-09-19T14:18:07.000Z'
group by 1, 2
```

but then I get this result:

```
date        name        count
-------------------------------
2015-09-19  New York    1
2015-09-19  Los Angeles 0
2015-09-19  Boston      0
2015-09-20  New York    1
2015-09-20  Los Angeles 0
2015-09-20  Boston      0
2015-09-21  New York    0
2015-09-21  Los Angeles 1
2015-09-21  Boston      0
…
```

It is not cummulative en there is row for each city instead of a column for each city. Does somebody know (the complicated) answer? If something is not clear just ask, In real live these are tables of 50.000 rows and I can't change the structure, I need this query for analytics purposes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns)

Comment: This may also help, if you do not need dynamic columns. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: Do you know the names of the cities you want to display, or is it dynamic? Also, do you know the maximum number of cities for each user, or is that dynamic?

Comment: I know the name of cities but it can change over time so it would be the best if it was dynamic

Comment: It is not a duplicate of the question you suggest because I also need it to be cumulative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the names of the cities, just use conditional aggregation:

```
select date(u.date_created), 
       sum(name = 'New York') as NewYork,
       sum(name = 'Los Angeles' as LosAngeles,
       sum(name = 'Boston') as Boston
from user u inner join
     setting s
     on u.id = s.user_id and
        setting_key = 'institution' inner join
     education_niveau en
     on s.setting_value = en.id
where u.date_created > '2015-09-19T14:18:07.000Z'
group by 1;
```

If you don't know the names of the cities or there are an unknown number, then you will need dynamic SQL -- that is, construct the SQL, prepare a statement, and then execute it.

EDIT:

It wasn't obvious at first that the question is about cumulative counts.  For that, use variables:

```
select dte,
       (@ny := @ny + NewYork) as NewYork,
       (@la := @la + LosAngeles) as LosAngeles,
       (@b := @b + Boston) as NewYork
from (select date(u.date_created) as dte, 
             sum(name = 'New York') as NewYork,
             sum(name = 'Los Angeles' as LosAngeles,
             sum(name = 'Boston') as Boston
      from user u inner join
           setting s
           on u.id = s.user_id and
              setting_key = 'institution' inner join
           education_niveau en
           on s.setting_value = en.id
      where u.date_created > '2015-09-19T14:18:07.000Z'
      group by 1
      order by 1
     ) us cross join
     (select @ny := 0, @la := 0, @b := 0) params
order by 1;
```

Comment: When I run your solution, I it's not cummulative so on the row for september 21 I want all users until then that have New York as city in their settings, If you could give an example for a dynamic query It would be awesome, I never worked with prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

You want a [pivot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table), which is not supported natively by mysql. However, this may work for you:

```
select date, group_concat(concat(name, '=', uid_count)) cities
from (
    select date(u.date_created) date, en.name, count(u.id) uid_count
    from user u
    join setting s on u.id = s.user_id
    join education_niveau en on s.setting_value = en.id
    where u.date_created > '2015-09-19T14:18:07.000Z'
    and setting_key = 'institution'
    group by 1, 2) x
group by 1
```

which will produce a result like:

```
date            Cities
------------------------------------------------------
2015-09-19      New York=1   
2015-09-20      New York=2
2015-09-21      New York=2,Los Angeles=1
```

The main advantage with this approach is the range of cities returned is totally based on the data.

Comment: Thanks for helping me but I need them in different columns to make a nice graph for the marketing people ;-)