# MySQL dynamic pivot with group concat

Tags: mysql, sql

Good morning everyone,

I have this view called salesData which basically looks like this and I want to pivot it dynamically since it might get updated later on.

```
+-------------+------------+------+
| salesTotal  | salesYear  |      |
+-------------+------------+------+
|    3016207  |       2008 |      |
|    3079627  |       2009 |      |
|    3133681  |       2010 |      |
|    3102944  |       2011 |      |
|    3126710  |       2012 |      |
|    3123600  |       2013 |      |
|    3116452  |       2014 |      |
|    3175186  |       2015 |      |
|     122371  |       2016 |
+-------------+------------+------+
```

I have designed the following query but it doesn't seem to work. MySQL workbench is giving me a weird error message :

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' MAX(CASE WHEN salesYear='2008 THEN 3016207 ELSE 0 END) AS 2008,MAX(CASE WHEN sa' at line 1
```

My query is as follows :

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN salesYear=''',salesYear,''' THEN ',salesTotal, ' ELSE 0 END) AS ',salesYear))
INTO @sql 
FROM salesData;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT, ', @sql, ' FROM salesData');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I would be grateful if someone could give me a hint. Thanks a lot :))

Oh btw, the result I'm looking for is this :

```
|    2008 |    2009 |    2010 |    2011 |    2012 |    2013 |    2014 |    2015 |  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--+
| 3133681 | 3133681 | 3133681 | 3102944 | 3126710 | 3126710 | 3126710 | 3126710 |  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--+
```

I get it using the following query but the whole point of this question is making that very query dynamic ;)) :

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN (salesYear='2010') THEN salesTotal ELSE 0 END) AS '2008',
  MAX(CASE WHEN (salesYear='2010') THEN salesTotal ELSE 0 END) AS '2009',
  MAX(CASE WHEN (salesYear='2010') THEN salesTotal ELSE 0 END) AS '2010',
  MAX(CASE WHEN (salesYear='2011') THEN salesTotal ELSE 0 END) AS '2011',
  MAX(CASE WHEN (salesYear='2012') THEN salesTotal ELSE 0 END) AS '2012',
  MAX(CASE WHEN (salesYear='2012') THEN salesTotal ELSE 0 END) AS '2013', 
  MAX(CASE WHEN (salesYear='2012') THEN salesTotal ELSE 0 END) AS '2014', 
  MAX(CASE WHEN (salesYear='2012') THEN salesTotal ELSE 0 END) AS '2015', 
  MAX(CASE WHEN (salesYear='2012') THEN salesTotal ELSE 0 END) AS '2016' 
  FROM salesData
```

EDIT : I found the error. The salesYear in this expression is not being concatenated properly.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN salesYear=''',salesYear,''' THEN ',salesTotal, ' ELSE 0 END) AS ',salesYear))
```

When I replace it by a string value as shown below, the query works perfectly. Anyone knows how to put that salesYear variable between single quotes ?

```
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN salesYear=''',salesYear,''' THEN ',salesTotal, ' ELSE 0 END) AS ','test'))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: I didn't know there was this thread here, but thank you for your extremely helpful comment. I figured out the answer to my problem by myself :)

Answer (score 0):

CONCAT('"',salesYear,'"') works. It seems that single quotes don't work :)