# mysql get tables with a changing number of columns

Tags: mysql

In my db, I have 2 tables: users and accounts. Every user bring several accounts. (users has UserID, and accounts has UserID, AccountID and createTime)

I need to get an SQL query that shows statistics about my users: a table that every **row** is how much accounts were created on every month, and the **columns** is the name of the users.

Can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  From what you wrote, the `users` table does not need to even be part of the query because it just contains an ID.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Comeon ... He wants us to do the work for him. Didn't you see he said *I need to get an SQL query that shows* :)

Comment: I don't even know how to start... @TimBiegeleisen . I don't know how to do a query with a changing number of columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: This question is for learning MySQL. I don't want you to do my job. I just invented 2 tables, in order to get a query and get the principle. I don't know how to do it. @Rahul

Comment: It's not a learning place. Moreover, morally you should ask for help only when you have done sufficient effort from your end.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the relation between `UserID` and `AccountID` is?  Will these always have a one-to-one relationship?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the idea is that one user have many accounts. 
for now, I can do
select count(AccountID) as num, UserID from accounts group by UserID
but i need it per month, this is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work for you:

```
SELECT UserId, DATE_FORMAT(CreatedTime, '%Y-%m'), COUNT(*) AS numAccountsPerUserPerMonth
FROM accounts
WHERE YEAR(createTime) = 2016
GROUP BY UserId, DATE_FORMAT(CreatedTime, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(CreatedTime, '%Y-%m') DESC, UserId
```

Comment: How about same month in difference year?

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(CreatedTime, '%Y-%m') @hvnis

Comment: I understand this solution. It does solve it but this is not actually what I asked.. I asked if I can do a query that his columns are the userid and rows are month, and in every cell there's the number of accounts that were opend, I actually wrote something like that in the comments above... But thanks for your solution.

Comment: @Joe3322 You are asking us for a pivot query, and if the number of users is very large, or not completely known, you will have to use dynamic SQL to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Great. Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have a resonably small, fixed number of users?  Or is the number of users unknown at design time?

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT UserId, YEAR(createTime) as YEAR, MONTH(createTime) as MONTH, COUNT(*) AS accCounter
FROM accounts
GROUP BY UserId, YEAR(createTime), MONTH(createTime)
```

This will give you a count for how many accounts each user opened in a month.