# ORDER BY within a distinct inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Was wondering if people could give me a hand here. I am currently updating some SQL code for a plugin I maintain, and I have hit a problem.

What I am trying to do is fetch data from one table, join it with another and then return the data to my PHP app. That is working, however - I want to order the data returned in descending order - this is proving difficult and doesn't seem to want to play ball.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.userid, s.id, u.user_nicename, u.user_login, u.display_name, u.id
       FROM wp_bbpas as s INNER JOIN wp_users as u
       ON s.userid = u.id
       ORDER BY s.id DESC
```

That returns everything in `wp_bbpas` and joins it with the `wp_users` table, but I actually only want to grab unique/distinct values.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you really intend from the query -- the query should be working.

Comment: I think s.id should be left out, since it appers to be the unique key of    wp_bbpas

Comment: @Turo that solved it, please submit an answer so I can mark it as resolved.

Comment: @Turo, so what if I wanted to select additional columns in this query? e.g, I also want to grab the date from the bbpas table. Obviously, this is going to be unique in 99% of cases - so how can I avoid dupes appearing in my results but also getting this data?

Comment: with DSTINCT you will not get dulicate rows,. you get one row for every set of different values of the columns from wp_bbpas.Sinc s.id is unique you get all rows. If you want a single row for each user you have to make a pivot table with the columns of wp_bbpas, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: @Turo I am not quite sure that is what I am looking for, also - I am unable to use those since I am working with WordPress here. Are you saying I am unable to get unique rows, inner joined, whilst also pulling through additional columns? I have tried Group by, however - the columns come through in a random order and thus not useful.

Comment: If you only need aggregates of the wp_bbpas-columns, you should group by wp_bbpas.userid and join the result table with wp_users. Then is the DISTINCT obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since s.id appears to be the unique key of wp_bbpas, it should be left out of the SELECT list to reduce the result to distinct users.