# Convert concat sql string to INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I have been looking for a way to convert this query / php to an INSERT INTO SELECT, but i can´t find a way to add values to the concat part of the query, any suggestions

```
$query = tep_db_query("SELECT DISTINCT products_attributes.products_id AS products_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 'filter_size_', products_attributes.options_id, '_', filter_options.filter_options_id) AS size FROM products_attributes INNER JOIN filter_options_to_values ON products_attributes.options_id = filter_options_to_values.options_id AND products_attributes.options_values_id = filter_options_to_values.values_id INNER JOIN filter_options ON filter_options_to_values.filter_options_id = filter_options.filter_options_id GROUP BY products_attributes.products_id;");
tep_db_query("TRUNCATE table " . $tableName);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $array = explode(',', $row['size']);
    $count = count($array);
    $string = '';
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        $string .= '1,';
    }
    $string = rtrim($string, ',');

    tep_db_query("INSERT INTO " . $tableName . " (products_id, " . $row['size'] . ") VALUES (" . $row['products_id'] . ", " . $string . ")");
}
```

This is what i am trying for the insert into but the problem is the dynimic cols size :

`SELECT DISTINCT
    products_attributes.products_id,
    filter_options_to_values.filter_options_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 'filter_size_', products_attributes.options_id, '_', filter_options.filter_options_id) AS size,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT '1') AS vals
  FROM
    products_attributes
    INNER JOIN filter_options_to_values ON products_attributes.options_id = filter_options_to_values.options_id AND products_attributes.options_values_id = filter_options_to_values.values_id
    INNER JOIN filter_options ON filter_options_to_values.filter_options_id = filter_options.filter_options_id
  WHERE products_attributes.options_quantity > 0
  GROUP BY products_attributes.products_id`

This is the schema:

`CREATE TABLE`products_temp`(`
products_id`int(11) NOT NULL default '0',`
final_price`decimal(15,4) default NULL,`
special_price`decimal(15,4) default NULL,`
manufacturers_id`int(11) default NULL,`
efv4`int(11) default NULL,`
efv5`int(11) default NULL,`
efv10`int(11) default NULL,`
products_date_added`datetime default NULL,`
filter_size_2_1`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_2`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_3`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_4`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_5`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_6`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_7`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_8`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_9`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_10`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_11`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_12`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_57`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_58`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_59`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_60`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_62`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_63`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_293`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_294`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_295`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_2_296`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_20`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_21`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_24`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_25`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_26`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_27`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_28`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_29`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_30`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_31`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_32`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_33`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_34`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_35`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_36`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_37`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_38`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_39`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_40`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_41`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_42`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_43`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_44`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_45`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_46`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_47`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_48`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_49`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_50`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_51`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_52`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_53`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_54`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_55`int(11) default NULL,`
filter_size_9_56`int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`products_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;`

Comment: The code is a tad unclear. Can you provide some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it? It would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `SELECT` statement has 4 fields. The table in which you are trying to insert has like 50. Your `SELECT` statement either needs to have 50 fields, or you need to change your temp table to 4 fields to match the results of your SELECT. My wager is that your schema for that table isn't so great and maybe the results of that SELECT are what you actually want in the table.
2. You are including `filter_options_id` in your SELECT so that should either be aggregated as well, or it should in the GROUP BY. Failure to do otherwise will mean that if there are multiple `filter_options_id` for each `products_id` your Database will just grab a random `filter_options_id` to include in the record. If there is only a single distinct `filter_options_id` for each `products_id` then just add it to the GROUP BY. If you ever upgrade to MySQL 5.7 this query will error out otherwise.
3. There is no need to use `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in the same query. You are aggregating one of your columns using `GROUP_CONCAT` so `GROUP BY` is the right choice. Drop the `DISTINCT` after you `SELECT`.
4. `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 1) as vals` is the same as just `1 as vals`

My only other thought is that perhaps you are aiming for a PIVOT query to fill your table, which is maybe why you were going after a group_concat. [Check out this question for information on how to pull that off.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns)