# Prepared Statement: Crosstab dynamic mysql query

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, crosstab

I am trying to make a cross tab pivot table. I need to get all teams from the database table dynamically on separate columns instead of specifying names of the teams in the query which I am currently doing. I have looked at another example i.e. [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns).

At the moment I am receiving the results fine from the database but only by manually typing what column I need in the query. See the example below:

```
SELECT IFNULL(DATE( date_posted ), 'Total') AS DATE, 
SUM(CASE WHEN added_by LIKE '%Team One%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Team1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN added_by LIKE '%Team Two%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Team2,
COUNT( added_by ) AS Daily_Total FROM teamdata WHERE status LIKE 
'%completed%' GROUP BY IFNULL(DATE( date_posted ), 'Total') DESC WITH ROLLUP;
```

Which displays 4 columns of DATE, Team1, Team2 and Daily_Total. But at a later stage there will be more columns to add in but to be done dynamically. I am trying to execute this prepared statement but to no success:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT 
CONCAT(  
    'sum(CASE WHEN added_by = ''', 
    added_by,  
    ''' THEN 1 else ''-'' END) AS `', added_by,
      '`' 
    ) 
) into @sql 
FROM teamdata;

SET @sql 
= CONCAT('SELECT IFNULL(DATE( date_posted ), \'Total\') AS DATE, ', @sql, ' 
        from teamdata
        WHERE status = \'completed\' 
        GROUP BY IFNULL(DATE( date_posted ), \'Total\') DESC WITH ROLLUP');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Please could I get further help on this.

Comment: Your second `SET` statement needs to escape the internal quote characters in `'Total'` and `'completed'`, and you have two commas after DATE.

Comment: So how do I go about to escape the internal quote character. I have edited the two commas after the date my apologies @BillKarwin

Comment: I don't understand why you would ask that, because you already did it in the first `SET` statement: use two single-quotes where you want one literal single-quote in your string. Or else use a backslash, like `\'`. Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Comment: Yes sorry you were right. I have edited the above code where I have added a backslash for 'Total' and 'completed'.

Comment: The query has been executed successfully but it gives me these results of the query:

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql ;# MySQL returned an empty result set     (i.e. zero rows).
EXECUTE stmt;# Rows: 132
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;# MySQL returned an empty result set     (i.e. zero rows).

But there is no table to display the results of the different teams.@BillKarwin

Comment: So is there any data in the table with status='completed'?

Comment: Yes there is rows that have status='completed' but should it not display a table after execution with columns of 'added_by' teams.@BillKarwin

Comment: Should there be a stored procedure created to see the data or is because I'm running the query through phpmyadmin whereby it is not displaying the results?

Comment: You weren't clear in your description how you were executing the statements. If you're using phpmyadmin, you should know that every page load of a PHP application uses a new connection to the database server, so you can't execute a prepared statement you created on a prior page load. You'll have to write this as an SQL script or a stored procedure.