# Pivot a table using `group_concat` and `group by`

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, group-concat

I have a table about questions and answers with two related columns with ID's. The answers to the questions can be numeric or alphanumeric like this:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║ visit_id ║ visit_child ║ question  ║ answer  ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║   121340 ║      104280 ║ How much? ║ 3       ║
║   121340 ║      104280 ║ How many? ║ 2       ║
║   121340 ║      104280 ║ Why?      ║ Because ║
║   121340 ║      104280 ║ Really?   ║ Yup     ║
║   121485 ║      114190 ║ How much? ║ 5       ║
║   121485 ║      114190 ║ How many? ║ 6       ║
║   121485 ║      114190 ║ Why?      ║ Why not ║
║   121485 ║      114190 ║ Really?   ║ Sure    ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

I want to pivot this info so the questions become the columns, and the given answers are placed properly. The result I'm looking for looks like this:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ visit_id ║ visit_child ║ How much? ║ How many? ║  Why?   ║ Really? ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║   121340 ║      104280 ║         3 ║         2 ║ Because ║ Yup     ║
║   121485 ║      114190 ║         5 ║         6 ║ Why not ║ Sure    ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

I've made my homework and read several Howto pivot in MySQL tutorials and I've come with this:

```
SELECT
    infoBase.visit_id,
    infoBase.visit_child,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('MAX(IF(infoBase.question = \'',question,'\', \'',answer,'\', 0)) AS \'',question,'\'',''), "\n"
    )
FROM    
  visits vi,
  infoBase
WHERE
  vi.id = infoBase.visit_child
GROUP BY
  infoBase.visit_id, infoBase.visit_child
```

What I get is the following:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ visit_id ║ visit_child ║                                                               GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(infoBase.question = \'',question,'\', \'',answer,'\', 0)) AS \'',question,'\'',''), "\n")                                                               ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║   121340 ║      104280 ║ MAX(IF(infoBase.question = 'How much?', '3', 0)) AS 'How much?',MAX(IF(infoBase.question = 'How many?', '2', 0)) AS 'How many?',MAX(IF(infoBase.question = 'Why?', 'Because', 0)) AS 'Why?',MAX(IF(infoBase.question = 'Really?', 'Yup', 0)) AS 'Really?'  ║
║   121485 ║      114190 ║ MAX(IF(infoBase.question = 'How much?', '5', 0)) AS 'How much?',MAX(IF(infoBase.question = 'How many?', '6', 0)) AS 'How many?',MAX(IF(infoBase.question = 'Why?', 'Why not', 0)) AS 'Why?',MAX(IF(infoBase.question = 'Really?', 'Sure', 0)) AS 'Really?' ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

The results retrieved by `group_concat` are correct but I'd like to, let's say "convert" that string to real columns.
This has to be done as dynamically as possible, because in the real table I don't know the exact number of questions and what are they, so I can't hardcode the questions in many `group_concat`.
What am I doing wrong??

THANKS!

P.S. This in an over simplification of a greater query. If more info needs to be added when new problems arise, I'll add it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns)

Comment: @shmosel Seems similar yes, I haven't seen the question before. I'll try to understand the answers there in the meanwhile. Thanks.

Comment: [_Here's_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot) how to dynamically generate the query.  Put that in a stored proc, then prepare & execute it.  `CALLing` that proc will do it all in "one step".

Answer (score 2):

try a query like this. its not tested !

```
SELECT
    infoBase.visit_id,
    infoBase.visit_child,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(question = 'How much?', answer ,'') SEPARATOR '' ) AS 'How much?' ,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(question = 'How many?', answer ,'') SEPARATOR '' ) AS 'How many?' ,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(question = 'Why?',      answer ,'') SEPARATOR '' ) AS 'Why?' ,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(question = 'Really?',   answer ,'') SEPARATOR '' ) AS 'Really?'
    )
FROM    
  visits vi,
  infoBase
WHERE
  vi.id = infoBase.visit_child
GROUP BY
  infoBase.visit_id;
```

Comment: OK I understand, but I'm trying to do this as dynamically as possible because in the real table I don't know how many questions are there and what are they. So I can't hardcode the questions. I've updated my question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: I see you use many `group_concat`, one for each column. Is there a way to emulate this dynamically? Using a loop or something?

Comment: @Metafaniel if you're using some coding language like Java you could iterate through the rows to create the SQL dynamically using something like JDBC.

Comment: @BerndBuffen Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.