# MySQL one result from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

**Hi all,**

I've the following tables:

jobs_active:

```
| id | date_id    | job_id | result   |
|-------------------------------------|
| 1  | 2017-08-28 | 1      | failed   |
|-------------------------------------|
| 2  | 2017-08-28 | 2      | failed   |
|_____________________________________|
```

jobs_history:

```
| id | job_id | date_id    | job_id | result   |
|----------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 1      | 2017-08-27 | 1      | failed   |
|----------------------------------------------|
| 2  | 1      | 2017-08-26 | 1      | success  |
|----------------------------------------------|
| 3  | 2      | 2017-08-27 | 2      | failed   |
|----------------------------------------------|
| 4  | 2      | 2017-08-26 | 2      | failed   |
|______________________________________________|
```

And I want to get this result:

```
                             (2017-08-28)| (2017-08-27)    | (2017-08-26)


| id | date_id    | job_id | result_now  | result_lastDay1 | result_lastDay2 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 2017-08-27 | 1      | failed      | failed          | success         |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2  | 2017-08-26 | 2      | failed      | failed          | failed          |
|____________________________________________________________________________|
```

The column "result_lastDayN" should be dynamic. So that I can select like 10 last days if needed.

I tried this already with join, and union, but I didn't get it to work.
Does anyone have an idea if this is possible?

Comment: You're basically after a dynamic pivot.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried with subqueries?

```
select ja.*,
(select result from jobs_history jh where job_id = ja.id and jh.date = j.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) result_lastDay1,
(select result from jobs_history jh where job_id = ja.id and jh.date = j.date - INTERVAL 2 DAY) result_lastDay2
 from 
jobs_active ja
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :) I tried subqueries I guess, but not in this way.