# Mysql Pivot some column in 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table like this:

```
id       key       year   month   value
---------------------------------------
1        AD        2000    1       5465
2        AD        2000    2       6445
3        JK        2000    1       7777
4        JK        2000    2       9999
```

I need to retrive the values like this:

```
key       2000-1  2000-2
------------------------
AD        5465    6445
JK        7777    9999
```

I'm having issues with creating the headers, concatenating `year` and `month` and displaying the `value` under the header.

I have another pivot procedure like this:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(combustible_id = ''',
            combustible_id,
            ''', valor_combustible, NULL)) AS ',
            CONCAT("`",admin_combustibles.nombre,"`")
        )
    ) INTO @SQL
FROM
    admin_indice_combustibles
INNER JOIN admin_combustibles 
   ON admin_indice_combustibles.combustible_id = admin_combustibles.id_combustible 
WHERE admin_indice_combustibles.estado = 1;

SET @SQL = CONCAT(
    'SELECT anio, mes, ',
    @SQL,
    ' FROM admin_indice_combustibles
      WHERE estado = 1 
      GROUP BY anio, mes 
      ORDER BY id_indice_combustible'
);

PREPARE stmt
FROM
    @SQL;
```

it is working, but it uses more data (because it has a JOIN with another table), now is easier, all the data is in just 1 table, but I can't get it. any hint please?

EDIT:

I'm trying with this code:

```
BEGIN

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
            ' MAX(IF(anio = ''',
            DIST.anio,
            ''' AND mes = ''', DIST.mes, ''', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS ',
            CONCAT("`",DIST.anio,"-`", DIST.mes,"`")
        )
    ) INTO @SQL
FROM
    admin_contratos_energia_adjudicadas_distribucion_mensual AS DIST
WHERE DIST.activo = 1;

SET @SQL = CONCAT(
    'SELECT DIST.key, DIST.contrato_id ',
    @SQL,
    ' FROM admin_contratos_energia_adjudicadas_distribucion_mensual AS DIST 
        WHERE activo = 1 
        GROUP BY DIST.key 
        ORDER BY DIST.contrato_id ');

PREPARE stmt
FROM
    @SQL;

EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

I'm getting the error:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX(IF(anio = '2016' AND mes = '1', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `2016-`1`,' at line 1

I just need to concatenate the year (anio) and month (mes) in the header, and give the value (energia_adjudicada_mwh) to them, for each year and mont, group by key...

This is the table that I have and the table that I need:
[image]

Comment: Then pls share what you have tried and the exact error message or unexpected behaviour.

Comment: So the code you show us works but for other tables? And doesn't work with your current table? What is the current query you are using and what result you have?

Comment: It's long, I was trying to make a sql fiddle but can't find a place where my code works... I will put anyway my code but it's not clear what I need with it because it's wrong, besides, in the example that I put I used 3 tables, now I only have to use 1 table.

Comment: You should ask a new question instead of adding a second unrelated question to your duplicate question (which isn't likely to get it reopened).

Comment: I've did that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617874/pivot-table-in-mysql-concatenating-two-rows-name-into-headers but now that one is marked as duplicate... it's a different question, not just asking for generic "pivot mysql"

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation like this:

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/XQJK62343)**

```
SELECT `key`,
        MAX( CASE WHEN `year` = 2000 and  `month` = 1 THEN `value` END) as `2000-01`,
        MAX( CASE WHEN `year` = 2000 and  `month` = 2 THEN `value` END) as `2000-02`
FROM t49613951
GROUP BY `key`;
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: mmm it's ok, the problem is that I put a demo of my situation, but in the real case I have 21 years, so it would be like 21*12 cases, that's too much. I'm trying to make those headers with a `select` not hard-coded

Comment: well you should be more specific next time. Also you didn't include all your tables in the original question. Check this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: That's exactly the same procedure that I have and I put in my example

Comment: Then I fail to see the problem, because you have something is already working.

Comment: I'm trying to use that but without the JOIN that I've specified in the body of my question

Comment: again, why is that a problem? and again you didnt show us what are those tables.