# Pivot table in MysQL, concatenating two rows name into headers

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, pivot-table

I have this table:
TABLE: admin_contratos_energia_adjudicada_distribucion_mensual
[image]

And I need a procedure to make this one:
[image]

I've made something similar but now I can't figure where should I change my code. My actual code is this one:

```
BEGIN

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
            ' MAX(IF(anio = ''',
            DIST.anio,
            ''' AND mes = ''', DIST.mes, ''', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS ',
            CONCAT("`",DIST.anio,"-`", DIST.mes,"`")
        )
    ) INTO @SQL
FROM
    admin_contratos_energia_adjudicadas_distribucion_mensual AS DIST
WHERE DIST.activo = 1;

SET @SQL = CONCAT(
    'SELECT DIST.key, DIST.contrato_id ',
    @SQL,
    ' FROM admin_contratos_energia_adjudicadas_distribucion_mensual AS DIST 
        WHERE activo = 1 
        GROUP BY DIST.key 
        ORDER BY DIST.contrato_id ');

PREPARE stmt
FROM
    @SQL;

EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

I'm getting this error:

Procedure execution failed
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX(IF(anio = '2016' AND mes = '1', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `2016-`1`,' at line 1

Any hint? I just need to concatenate the 'anio' and 'mes' in the headers of the new one, and put there the 'energia adjudicada mwh' value.

Please, don't post answers with `CASE` because the table has like 20 years, I need to retrieve the years with a query.

EDIT: Edited some parts near to `mes`

```
BEGIN

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(anio = ''',
            anio,
            ''' AND mes = ''', mes, ''', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS ',
            CONCAT("`",mes,"-", anio,"`")
        )
    ) INTO @SQL
FROM
    admin_contratos_energia_adjudicadas_distribucion_mensual
WHERE activo = 1;

SET @SQL = CONCAT(
    'SELECT key, contrato_id, ',
    @SQL,
    ' FROM admin_contratos_energia_adjudicadas_distribucion_mensual  
        WHERE activo = 1 
        GROUP BY key 
        ORDER BY contrato_id ');

PREPARE stmt
FROM
    @SQL;

EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Error:

Procedure execution failed
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, contrato_id, MAX(IF(anio = '2016' AND mes = '1', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NU' at line 1

EDIT 2:

I got this with select @SQL:

```
SELECT   key, 
         contrato_id, 
         Max(IF(anio = '2016' 
AND      mes = '1', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `1-2016`, 
         Max(IF(anio = '2016' 
AND      mes = '2', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `2-2016`, 
         Max(IF(anio = '2016' 
AND      mes = '3', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `3-2016`, 
         Max(IF(anio = '2016' 
AND      mes = '4', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `4-2016`, 
         Max(IF(anio = '2016' 
AND      mes = '5', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `5-2016`, 
         Max(IF(anio = '2016' 
AND      mes = '6', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `6-2016`, 
         Max(IF(anio = '2016' 
AND      mes = '7', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `7-2016`, 
         Max(IF(anio = '2016' 
AND      mes = '8', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `8-2016`, 
         Max(IF(anio = '2016' 
AND      mes = '9', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `9-2016`, 
         Max(IF(anio = '2016' 
AND      mes = '10', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `10-2016`, 
         Max(IF(anio = '2016' 
AND      mes = '11', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `11-2016`, 
         Max(IF(anio = '2016' 
AND      mes = '12', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS `12-2016`, 
         Max(IF(anio = '2017' 
AND      mes = '1', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS 
from     admin_contratos_energia_adjudicadas_distribucion_mensual 
WHERE    activo = 1 
GROUP BY KEY 
ORDER BY contrato_id
```

LAST EDIT (with correct answer): if anyone needs the final code... is this:

```
BEGIN
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 9999;
SET @SQL = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(anio = ''',
            anio,
            ''' AND mes = ''', mes, ''', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS ',
            CONCAT("`",mes,"-", anio,"`")
        )
    ) INTO @SQL
FROM
    admin_contratos_energia_adjudicadas_distribucion_mensual
WHERE activo = 1;

SET @SQL = CONCAT(
    'SELECT `key`, contrato_id, ',
    @SQL,
    ' FROM admin_contratos_energia_adjudicadas_distribucion_mensual  
        WHERE activo = 1 
        GROUP BY `key` 
        ORDER BY contrato_id ');

PREPARE stmt
FROM
@SQL;

EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

#select @SQL;

END
```

Comment: You definitely have an extra backtick before the month value in the generated field name. Pls include the generated sql statement in your question. That would make it simpler to identify the issue (based on that even yourself may find the bug...).

Comment: Ah, you have a missing colon after contrato_id as well.

Comment: @Shadow I habe edited my question with some new code, but I have the same error.

Comment: As I wrote in my first comment, print out the final sql statement for debugging purposes. You should be able to spot the issue with it yourself.

Comment: I don't know how to get it, I just run it with Navicat and I got the error that I've mentioned

Comment: select @sql - just make sure you comment out the prepare - execute - deallocate.

Comment: @Shadow done (edited my question)

Comment: And now check it for syntax errors... (hint: you are not getting exactly the same error message as last time and the error message tells you where to look for the syntax error).

Comment: Thanks man, now I can see at least where is my error. There are 2, first one KEY is a private word... I have to use `key`, second, there's a `Max(IF(anio = '2017' 
AND      mes = '1', energia_adjudicada_mwh, NULL)) AS ` mal concatenated that I have to repair. Doing the query without that last MAX it works ok

Comment: Lol, now I'm reading that `Note: the GROUP_CONCAT result length is limited to the value of the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024` that's why my query got cut at that point... now I'll have to make another question.

Comment: Done, I have edited my question with the last code as the correct one, finally, thank you very much @Shadow

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot for a stored proc to generate the code.