# Query for concating two rows of same id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a table which got structure like this:-

```
chkey    chvalue        updatetime          unit_id
ch1       27            7/11/2018 1:08          35
ch2       89            7/12/2018 1:08          35
ch1       26            7/13/2018 2:08          46
ch2       77            7/14/2018 2:08          46
ch1       24            7/15/2018 3:08          47
ch2       77            7/16/2018 3:08          47
```

what i want is a query for generating a result like this:-

```
    updatetime          ch1     ch2     unit_id
    7/11/2018 1:08       27      89      35
    7/11/2018 2:08       26      77      46
    7/11/2018 3:08       24      77      47
```

**NOTE:** chkey's can be upto ch1....ch64 for any unit_id.

Comment: i think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: kind off similar because the unit_id can have multiple chkey let's say upto 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select min(updatetime),
       max(case when chkey = 'ch1' then chvalue end) as ch1,
       max(case when chkey = 'ch2' then chvalue end) as ch2,
       unit_id
from t
group by unit_id;
```

You would just add 62 more expressions for each `chkey`.

Comment: what if i say there are multiple rows of same unit_id and i want all of the data of that unit_id.....and yes tried this query with where clause like  "where unit_id='35'" and what i want this is to be dynamic like any unit_id can have multiple chkey in this case it have only two chkey,some unit may have 3,4 or 64.

Comment: @savyaDhurve . . . Then I think you would have a different question.  It is only possible to answer the question that you ask which is what this answer does.  If you have another question, ask it as a *question* not a *comment*.

Comment: the question link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322324/sql-query-for-concating-multiple-rows-with-same-ids-but-with-different-values-wh)