# SQl Query for concating multiple rows with same ids but with different values which having same datefields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a database with following data fields:-

```
chkey    chvalue        updatetime          unit_id
ch1       27            7/11/2018 1:08          35
ch2       89            7/12/2018 1:08          35
ch1       26            7/13/2018 2:08          46
ch2       77            7/14/2018 2:08          46
ch1       24            7/15/2018 3:08          47
ch2       77            7/16/2018 3:08          47
ch1       28            7/11/2018 6:18          35
ch2       86            7/12/2018 6:18          35
ch1       27            7/11/2018 7:18          35
ch2       86            7/12/2018 7:18          35
ch1       27            7/11/2018 9:18          48
ch2       86            7/12/2018 9:18          48
ch3       23            7/11/2018 9:18          48
ch4       99            7/12/2018 9:18          48
.....
```

what i want is a query for generating a result like this:-

**for unit_id = 35**

```
     updatetime         ch1     ch2     unit_id
    7/11/2018 1:08       27      89      35
    7/11/2018 6:18       28      86      35
    7/11/2018 7:18       27      86      35
```

**for unit_id= 46**

```
      updatetime        ch1     ch2     unit_id
    7/11/2018 2:08       27      77      46
```

**for unit_id=47**

```
     updatetime         ch1     ch2     unit_id
    7/11/2018 3:08       24      77      47
```

**for unit_id=48**

```
      updatetime        ch1     ch2     ch3    ch4    unit_id
    7/11/2018 9:18       27      86     23     99         48
```

**NOTE:** chkey's can be upto ch1....ch64 for any unit_id it can be anything let's say a unit with ch5 and so on .

Comment: I would have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428993/understanding-pivot-function-in-t-sql as you are after a PIVOT query.

Comment: @simonWhale MySQL support PIVOT? your link tagged SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with PIVOT option.[Pivot a Table in MySQL](http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/)