# PHP - SQL: Combine two rows into single row with multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[O/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpglt.png)I want to join two rows into single row with multiple columns(dynamically) using SQL Query in PHP.

[image: SQL Table tf4i]

[image: Desired Output]

Output should be grouped by tf4hid and date.

**SQL Query**

```
Select tf4hid,tf4iid,date,product,planqty
from tf4i
group by date,product
```

This prints row by row but i need to generate columns based on the available products in the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggregate function.

```
SELECT tf4hid,
       date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN product = 'MS(EURO-IV)' THEN planqty END) 'MS(EURO-IV)', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN product = 'HSD(Euro-IV)' THEN planqty END) 'HSD(Euro-IV)', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN product = 'Super_Petrol' THEN planqty END) 'Super_Petrol'  
FROM tf4i
GROUP BY tf4hid,date
```

**EDIT**

dynamic pivot version. create the sql then execute dynamically.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      ' MAX(CASE WHEN product = ''',
      product,
      ''' THEN planqty END) ''',
      product , ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tf4i;



SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT tf4hid,
                          date, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM tf4i
                   GROUP BY tf4hid,date');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://rextester.com/XHK33569)

Comment: It is working but Product needs to be fetched dynamically. Any idea for that by using php

Comment: @SriVathsan You can try to use dynamic pivot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: I have tried but i didn't understand it. could you please help me

Comment: I have added O/P error of result. Could you please figure it out

Comment: Any idea how to add this to php.