# How to pivot a single table in MySQL script?

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have SQL Table that looks like this :

```
select PARAMNAME, PARAMVALUE, INTERFACEID from RTVS_RESPONSE WHERE INTERFACEID IN ('MPN.INQUIRY.DJA')
```

> ```
> PARAMNAME     PARAMVALUE                          INTERFACEID     
> billingInfo1  021076427070122                     MPN.INQUIRY.DJA
> billingInfo2  411122                              MPN.INQUIRY.DJA
> billingInfo3  100                                 MPN.INQUIRY.DJA
> billingInfo4  03032014                            MPN.INQUIRY.DJA
> billingInfo5  000000000000000                     MPN.INQUIRY.DJA
> billingInfo6  JL.MESJID IV NO.19,JAKARTA UTARA    MPN.INQUIRY.DJA
> billingInfo7  900019191818181778                  MPN.INQUIRY.DJA
> amount            89002                           MPN.INQUIRY.DJA
> customerName  NPWP DUMMY DJA                      MPN.INQUIRY.DJA
> responseCode  00                                  MPN.INQUIRY.DJA
> ```

And This :

```
select PARAMNAME, PARAMVALUE, INTERFACEID from RTVS_RESPONSE WHERE INTERFACEID IN ('MPN.INQUIRY.DJBC')
```

> ```
> PARAMNAME     PARAMVALUE                          INTERFACEID     
> billingInfo1  021076427070122                     MPN.INQUIRY.DJBC
> billingInfo2  411122                              MPN.INQUIRY.DJBC
> billingInfo3  100                                 MPN.INQUIRY.DJBC
> billingInfo4  03032014                            MPN.INQUIRY.DJBC
> billingInfo5  000000000000000                     MPN.INQUIRY.DJBC
> billingInfo6  JL.MESJID IV NO.19,JAKARTA UTARA    MPN.INQUIRY.DJBC
> billingInfo7  900019191818181778                  MPN.INQUIRY.DJBC
> amount            89001                           MPN.INQUIRY.DJBC
> customerName  NPWP DUMMY DJBC                     MPN.INQUIRY.DJBC
> responseCode  00                                  MPN.INQUIRY.DJBC
> ```

I would like to create a pivot table so that `PARAMVALUE` became `column name VALUE`.

Like this :

```
INTERFACEID | billingInfo1 | billingInfo2 | billingInfo3 | billingInfo4 | billingInfo5 | billingInfo6 | billingInfo7 | amount | customerName | responseCode
```

Fyi, this is a single table. and many other question is asking for joining 2 different table. I don't think it's duplicated to any one else.

Comment: I don't think its a duplicated. since my question is about a single table. and that one you mention is a solution for pivoting 2 table ( a join table ). cmiiw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i think you can get excepted result using :

```
create temporary table tempTable
(
PARAMNAME varchar(40) not null,    PARAMVALUE  varchar(40) not null,                        INTERFACEID varchar(40) not null 
);


INSERT INTO TEMPTABLE ()
SELECT 'billingInfo1',  '021076427070122', 'MPN.INQUIRY.DJA'
UNION
SELECT 'billingInfo2', '411122','MPN.INQUIRY.DJA'
UNION
SELECT 'billingInfo3','100','MPN.INQUIRY.DJA'
UNION
SELECT 'billingInfo4','03032014','MPN.INQUIRY.DJA'
UNION
SELECT 'billingInfo5','000000000000000','MPN.INQUIRY.DJA'
UNION
SELECT 'billingInfo6','JL.MESJID IV NO.19,JAKARTA UTARA','MPN.INQUIRY.DJA'
UNION
SELECT 'billingInfo7','900019191818181778','MPN.INQUIRY.DJA'
UNION
SELECT 'amount','89002','MPN.INQUIRY.DJA'
UNION
SELECT 'customerName','NPWP DUMMY DJA','MPN.INQUIRY.DJA'
UNION
SELECT 'responseCode','00','MPN.INQUIRY.DJA';

-- SELECT * FROM TEMPTABLE;


SELECT INTERFACEID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PARAMNAME = 'billingInfo1' THEN PARAMVALUE ELSE NULL END) AS 'billingInfo1',
    MAX(CASE WHEN PARAMNAME = 'billingInfo2' THEN PARAMVALUE ELSE NULL END) AS 'billingInfo2',
    MAX(CASE WHEN PARAMNAME = 'billingInfo3' THEN PARAMVALUE ELSE NULL END) AS 'billingInfo3',
    MAX(CASE WHEN PARAMNAME = 'billingInfo4' THEN PARAMVALUE ELSE NULL END) AS 'billingInfo4',
    MAX(CASE WHEN PARAMNAME = 'billingInfo5' THEN PARAMVALUE ELSE NULL END) AS 'billingInfo5',
    MAX(CASE WHEN PARAMNAME = 'billingInfo6' THEN PARAMVALUE ELSE NULL END) AS 'billingInfo6',
    MAX(CASE WHEN PARAMNAME = 'billingInfo7' THEN PARAMVALUE ELSE NULL END) AS 'billingInfo7',
    MAX(CASE WHEN PARAMNAME = 'amount' THEN PARAMVALUE ELSE NULL END) AS 'amount',
    MAX(CASE WHEN PARAMNAME = 'customerName' THEN PARAMVALUE ELSE NULL END) AS 'customerName',
    MAX(CASE WHEN PARAMNAME = 'responseCode' THEN PARAMVALUE ELSE NULL END) AS 'responseCode'

FROM TEMPTABLE
GROUP BY INTERFACEID;

drop temporary table temptable;
```

But if you have other column dynamicaly you have to use Dynamic SQL query using EXECUTE example was find here : [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns)

Comment: @ i just edit the question. please kindly help..

Comment: Wow it still works like a charm! Thanks for your help !
You're the real life savior !!

Comment: Glad to help you :).