# MySQL 1064 syntax error in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have stored procedure in local mysql version 5.7.18-log which has this block
but it is not working on AWS RDS 5.7.23-log.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(' GROUP_CONCAT(IF(slf.Name = ''', t.NAME, ''' , slfv.Text, NULL)) AS ', t.NAME )) INTO @PivotQuery
FROM (SELECT slf.NAME  FROM searchlogfields slf GROUP BY slf.NAME) t;
```

It throws

> syntax error on "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(' GROUP_CONCAT(IF(slf.Name = ''', t.NAME, ''' , s"

When tried to run this part of the stored procedure in the new query without Begin&End it works.

Comment: Can you show us the entire procedure? at least up to and including this line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns)

Comment: The possible duplicate is there because i noticed the `@PivotQuery` variable so iam assuming you are trying the make a dynamic pivot query.