# MYSQL - Turn rows of data into column

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a set of data like below image.

[image]

How to turn this data into column like below

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| pcamhd_projectid | pcamhd_year |    1    |    2   |    3   |   4   |   5   |   6  |   7   |   8   |   9   |   10   |   11   |   12   |
| 987              | 2018        | 1782.52 | 214.66 |  62.52 | 0.00  | 0.00  | 0.00 | 0.00  | 20.00 | 0.00  | 0.00   | 0.00   | 0.00   |
```

Comment: Please don't add tables as image, i could help, but i really don't want to type your table.

Comment: This question is a duplication for sure...A Stackoverflow search ["MySQL pivot"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL+pivot) or  ["MySQL convert records into columns"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MySQL+convert+records+into+columns) should provide more then enough information/examples to solve..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a pivot query, i will demonstrate it:

```
 SELECT pcamhd_projectid,
sum(pcamhd_debtrepayment*(1-abs(sign(pcamhd_period-1)))) as '1',
sum(pcamhd_debtrepayment*(1-abs(sign(pcamhd_period-2)))) as '2',
sum(pcamhd_debtrepayment*(1-abs(sign(pcamhd_period-3)))) as '3',
sum(pcamhd_debtrepayment*(1-abs(sign(pcamhd_period-4)))) as '4',
sum(pcamhd_debtrepayment*(1-abs(sign(pcamhd_period-5)))) as '5',
sum(pcamhd_debtrepayment*(1-abs(sign(pcamhd_period-6)))) as '6',
sum(pcamhd_debtrepayment*(1-abs(sign(pcamhd_period-7)))) as '7',
sum(pcamhd_debtrepayment*(1-abs(sign(pcamhd_period-8)))) as '8',
sum(pcamhd_debtrepayment*(1-abs(sign(pcamhd_period-9)))) as '9',
sum(pcamhd_debtrepayment*(1-abs(sign(pcamhd_period-10)))) as '10',
sum(pcamhd_debtrepayment*(1-abs(sign(pcamhd_period-11)))) as '11',
sum(pcamhd_debtrepayment*(1-abs(sign(pcamhd_period-12)))) as '12'
FROM test.pc_amortizeheader
group by pcamhd_projectid;
```

- **sing (x)** returns **-1,0,+1** for values **x < 0, x = 0, x >0** respectively
- **abs( sign(x) )** returns **0 if x = 0** else, **1 if x > 0 or x < 0**
- **1 - abs( sign(x) )** complement of the above, since this returns **1 only if x = 0**

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. Many example from the internet always group by ID. But my question is not suitable to group by ID. It suppose to group by projectid like your solution. thanks!