# SQL Counting Distinct Values From Table With multiple Where possibilities

Tags: mysql, sql

The question is simple. How do i combine the following 2 sql queries into one.

I am using MYSQL v8.0.16 on the MYSQL Workbase UI.

```
SELECT Node_Type, COUNT(*)  AS `count`
FROM node_table_vis 
WHERE Node_SpinePlanID = "1"
GROUP BY Node_Type;
```

RETURNS

```
TYPE - COUNT
-----------
AGN     18
TJ      26
DSLAM   15
PON     18
CCJ     17
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT Node_SpinePlanID
FROM node_table_vis
WHERE Node_Exchange = "Exchange 1";
```

Thats returns

```
SpinePlanID
------------
1
5
10
```

So essentially what i want is query that looks like this?

```
SELECT Node_Type, COUNT(*)  AS `count`
FROM node_table_vis 
WHERE Node_SpinePlanID =
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Node_SpinePlanID
    FROM node_table_vis
    WHERE Node_Exchange = "Exchange 1";
)
GROUP BY Node_Type;
```

So I get table that looks like

```
TYPE -  1  -  5  -  10
-----------------------
AGN     18    x     y
TJ      26    x     y
DSLAM   15    x     y
PON     18    x     y
CCJ     17    x     y
```

So this is just throwing errors and not producing the goods. I was able to find the answer the top query, i was able to make the bottom, however i am unable to find an answer to combine both.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

UPDATE/EDIT

I have the following ...

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 10000;
SET @sql = null;
SELECT group_concat(distinct
    concat(
        'SUM(Node_SpinePlanID = ''',
        Node_SpinePlanID,
        ''',) AS ',
        Node_SpinePlanID
    )
) INTO @sql 
FROM node_table_vis;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Node_Type, ', @sql, ' FROM node_table_vis GROUP BY Node_Type');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

However the PREPARE stmt is not working? Getting error Code 1064 You have an SQL Error Syntax?

Any Advice on this one?

Comment: Use `WHERE Node_SpinePlanID in ( ... )`

Comment: If the columns would change dynamically, you should look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for conditional aggregation?

```
SELECT Node_Type,
       SUM(Node_SpinePlanID = 1) AS count_1,
       SUM(Node_SpinePlanID = 5) AS count_5,
       SUM(Node_SpinePlanID = 10) AS count_10
FROM node_table_vis 
GROUP BY Node_Type;
```

You can also put the values into rows:

```
SELECT Node_Type, Node_SpinePlanID, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM node_table_vis 
GROUP BY Node_Type, Node_SpinePlanID;
```

Without dynamic SQL, probably the best you can do is to put the values in a single row is to put them in a string with two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT Node_Type, GROUP_CONCAT(Node_SpinePlanID, ':', cnt SEPARATOR ',')
FROM (SELECT Node_Type, Node_SpinePlanID, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM node_table_vis 
      GROUP BY Node_Type, Node_SpinePlanID
     ) ts
GROUP BY Node_Type;
```

Comment: This return what i need. however the list of SpinePlanID can change depending on the search Exchange?

Comment: I could work with the query. as it gives me the results and I can filter by the exchange so i can make that work. if you see my edit, someone suggested prepared statements? I think I'm close however i minor issue if you see my edit above.