# MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns truncating key value

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I am trying to dynamically pivot the key value pairs in the table below.

```
+-----------------+-----------------------------+-------+
| id | category   | name                        | value |
+-----------------+-----------------------------+-------+
|  1 | acme       | 2fa                         |   0   |      
|  2 | acme       | abc_processing_date         | today |        
|  3 | acme       | activate_new_approve_person |   1   |         
|  4 | acme       | activate_new_schdule        |   1   |
|  5 | acme       | additional_footer_for_person|  NULL |   
+-----------------+-----------------------------+-------+
```

Running my query below I am getting the error

> `'-new-schedule,IFNULL(IF(z_tmp_admin_system_settings.name = 'additional_footer_fo' at line 1`

I this developed using method described by Taryn in [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns).

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000;
SET @sql = '';

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                    CONCAT(
                            'IFNULL(IF(z_tmp_admin_system_settings.name = ''',
                            name,
                            ''', value, NULL), NULL) AS ',
                            name
                        )
           )
INTO @sql
FROM z_tmp_admin_system_settings;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT subdomain, ', @sql, ' FROM name GROUP BY subdomain');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code - by descreasing gravity:

- you need to select `from z_tmp_admin_system_settings`, not `from name`
- the column to group by is called `category`, not `subdomain`
- since the principle of the query is to use aggregation, you need an aggregate functions for the generated columns, such as `MAX()`; old versions of MySQL tolerate not using an aggregate function on non-aggregated columns, but that's not something to get accustomed to
- it is a good practice to surround the name of the columns with backticks, in case one of the name clashes with a reserved word (this is not the case in your sample data, but it is probably not comprehensive)
- `DISTINCT` is probably not needed, unless you have duplicated `name`s per category (in this case, feel free to add it back to the below code)
- Side note: `IFNULL(..., NULL)` is a no-op

Code:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000;
SET @sql = '';

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT('MAX(IF(z_tmp_admin_system_settings.name = ''', name, ''', value, NULL)) AS `', name, '`')
)
INTO @sql
FROM z_tmp_admin_system_settings;
SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT category, ', 
    @sql, 
    ' FROM z_tmp_admin_system_settings GROUP BY category'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/drzR8reGwLmiggjXw1FSP1/0)**:

```
| category | 2fa | abc_processing_date | activate_new_approve_person | activate_new_schdule | additional_footer_for_person |
| -------- | --- | ------------------- | --------------------------- | -------------------- | ---------------------------- |
| acme     | 0   | today               | 1                           | 1                    |                              |
```

Comment: How would I modify the statement to create a new table from the results

Comment: @Adam: just `SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE AS SELECT category, ', @sql, ...`

Comment: getting row size is too large.  Trying to add `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` to end of the `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` but it did not work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Adam: hard to tell without seeing actual data. You would need to ask a *new* question, as comments are basically not meant for this. Also if my answer was helpful and properly responded to your *original* question, please upvote/accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of your names have hyphens in them; one of them ends with `-new-schedule` (although the sample data posted has `activate_new_schedule` -- is that accurate?). You need to enclose the names in backticks to escape these names when using them as aliases.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                    CONCAT(
                            'IFNULL(IF(z_tmp_admin_system_settings.name = ''',
                            name,
                            ''', value, NULL), NULL) AS `',
                            name,
                            '`'
                        )
           )
INTO @sql
FROM z_tmp_admin_system_settings;
```