# MySQL Group by with named columns from grouped data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pivot

I'm writing an application to record 10 pin bowling game results. I've done the submission bit but I'm stuck on displaying the results. Here is the structure:

```
id fixture_id member_id team_id game score
 1          1         1       1    1   189
 2          1         1       1    2   167
 3          1         1       1    3   190
 4          1         2       2    1   100
 5          1         2       2    2   167
 6          1         2       2    3   158
```

In the example above I am assuming each person played 3 games, however any number of games could be played.

How can I get the data in a more friendly format?

For example:

```
id - fixture_id - member_id - team_id - game_1 - game_2 - game_3
```

where columns game_1, game_2, and game_3 (and so forth) correspond to the score for that game.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns)

Comment: @AnkitBajpai kind of yes. It is similar to the answer from GMB however uses 2 tables but the selected answer in that provides further reading i can do to try learn some more myself.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot with conditional aggregation, but that requires that you know in advance how many columns you want to generate. The below solution handles up to 3 games per user (you can extend the `select` clause with more `max(case ...)` expressions to handle more than that):

```
select  
    fixture_id,
    member_id,
    team_id,
    max(case when game = 1 then score end) game_1,
    max(case when game = 2 then score end) game_2,
    max(case when game = 3 then score end) game_3
from mytable
group by 
    fixture_id,
    member_id,
    team_id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cdce94a607e8533f65e129839a0dedcd)**:

```
fixture_id | member_id | team_id | game_1 | game_2 | game_3
---------: | --------: | ------: | -----: | -----: | -----:
         1 |         1 |       1 |    189 |    167 |    190
         1 |         2 |       2 |    100 |    167 |    158
```

Comment: This answer will not help OP as he already mention that no of games is dynamic as any no of games can be played.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: I updated my answer to be explicit about that.

Comment: OP have already said that any number of games can be played. So YOu must provide the generic enough solution.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai the generic answer would include a potentially infinite list of columns. This would make the table unreadable!

Comment: @LelioFaieta, Please see my answer, what I was trying to say.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai There are no obligations upon contributors to this forum

Comment: @Strawberry, I agree that there is no obligation, But it must be absolute responsibility of every contributor to provide most generic and correct solution as possible.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai No. That's simply not the case.

Comment: Ok, So can we provide any garbage here also?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below dynamic script to generate your desired result without knowing the no of games played already -

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(game = ''',
      game,
      ''', game, NULL)) AS game_',
      game
    )
  ) into @sql
FROM mytable;

set @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, fixture_id, member_id, team_id, ', @sql, ' from mytable group by id, fixture_id, member_id, team_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f3b2b18ecd0f9e13e34cfe504f2c6cf) is the demo.