# Dynamic pivot table with column names as row-primary keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, dynamic-pivot

I need help regarding a thing I've been doing. So, I have stored some access data in this table:

```
SELECT * FROM MASTER_ROLE;
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| userid | Page A | Page B | Page C | Page D | Page E | Page F | Page G | Page H | Page I |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
|      1 |      0 |      2 |      1 |      1 |      0 |      2 |      0 |      1 |      2 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I am storing data like this because I need to give any 1 of 3 levels of access (Restricted, User and Admin) **individually for different pages to different people**. So, if a person is an admin for Page A, he might be restricted from Page B. Here, I have shown 0: admin, 1: user and 2: restricted.

Therefore, when a user logs in successfully, I need to send this table to the front end:

```
//query to retreive access rights for userid=1;

+-----------+-------+
| Page Name | Right |
+-----------+-------+
|    Page A |     0 |
|    Page B |     2 |
|    Page C |     1 |
|    Page D |     1 |
|    Page E |     0 |
|    Page F |     2 |
|    Page G |     0 |
|    Page H |     1 |
|    Page I |     2 | 
+-----------+-------+
```

This is because in the front end, I will traverse through this table using a loop and disable all the pages with access right = Restricted.

**ALSO, PLEASE NOTE THAT THE QUERY NEEDS TO BE DYNAMIC SO THAT IT DOES NOT NEED TO BE CHANGED WHEN THE NUMBER OF PAGES (IE. NO. OF COLUMNS IN THE MASTER_ROLE TABLE INCREASE.**

Thank you very much :)

Comment: `I am storing data like this because...` This is not a justification. Just fix your data model.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns ?

Comment: Stored proc to dynamically build and execute a pivot:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot