# Transposing data from multiple rows into a single row multiple columns using DYNAMIC MYSQL PIVOT

Tags: mysql

This question is different from what have been searching on in that it selects from more than one column  before creating the pivot table
I have a table structure similar to this

```
CREATE TABLE score (
id int,
reg_id varchar(5),
test1 int(5),
exam int(5),
subject int(5),
term VARCHAR(5)
)


CREATE TABLE subject (
    id int,
    subject_name varchar(5)
    )
```

I want to be able to select more than one  value e.g test1 and exam into different column in the DYNAMIC MYSQL PIVOT TABLE
I have seen similar example like [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)
, [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns) but they seems to be selecting only 1 matching value into the dynamic pivot table.  I have tried  writing something like this

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when subject = ''',
      subject,
      ''' then test1 end)AS `',
      (select subject_name from subject where id=subject), '`',

        'SUM(case when subject = ''',
      subject,
      ''' then exam end)AS `',
      (select subject_name from subject where id=subject), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  scores;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT reg_id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM scores  where term="First term"
                   GROUP BY reg_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

but it is not working thank you

I want an output similar to this after the tranpose.

```
regid-------maths test----maths exam-----english test------english exam
3m ---------    10    -----   23     ----     12         ------- 59
```

Comment: Can you add sample data as text please.

Comment: AND do add subject table definition and sample.