# Query works in mysql but does not display correctly in grafana

Tags: grafana

So I'm just building a small project that involves the use of MySQL and Grafana.

Here's my MySQL query and it's corresponding correct output:

```
select state, sum(total_cases) from PolDATA group by state order by sum(total_cases) desc limit 5;
```

Correct output: [image: Output]

I have enetered the same query in Grafana as well. Also, the format is Table and not Time Series. The output in Grafana is this: [image: Grafana output] when I display as a gauge. Here I do not want the text to be **sum(total_cases)**. I want it to display the name of the state. I tried altering it in Visualization->Field->Title but that changes all the labels to the same value. I even tried adding to the query `select sum(total_cases) as "Sometext"` but it changes all the labels to "**Sometext**" instead.

Help is appreciated. Thank you (:

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with MySql, so don't set irrelevant tags.

Comment: i'm sorry but isn't the MySQL query a part of MySQL? because there's a possibility that my query might be incorrect for usage in grafana

Comment: The query works fine. Your question is about grafana.

Answer (score 1):

- First you need to configure your Grafana as the below image. 
  [image]
- You need to write pivot table query as below.

```
select
sum(case when state = 'MAHARASHTRA'  then total_cases else 0 end) as "MAHARASHTRA",
sum(case when state = 'GUJARAT'  then total_cases else 0 end) as "GUJARAT",
sum(case when state = 'MADHYA PRADESH'  then total_cases else 0 end) as "MADHYA PRADESH",
sum(case when state = 'RAJASTHAN'  then total_cases else 0 end) as "RAJASTHAN",
sum(case when state = 'DELHI'  then total_cases else 0 end) as "DELHI"
from PolDATA
group by state
```

E.g.
[image]

Note: If your "state" column is dynamic, then you need to try dynamic pivoting.

E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12599372/4249637