# Create an insert to pivot value pair values into a table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, sql-insert, create-table

I have a value pair table that I want to use to create a member table

Based on Taryns answer to this question

[MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns/12599372#12599372)

I have this code that creates selects the data, which works fine

```
    SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN wpdg_usermeta.meta_key = ''',
      meta_key,
      ''' THEN wpdg_usermeta.meta_value END) `',
      meta_key, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
wpdg_usermeta
WHERE
wpdg_usermeta.meta_key like "member_%"
;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT user_id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM wpdg_usermeta 
                   GROUP BY user_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

So, my question is - does anyone know how I could alter this to run an INSERT instead of a SELECT so that I could populate the new member table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a new table with the results of the dynamic query. I think the simplest approach is to use the `create table ... as select ...` syntax.

This requires very few changes to your code, and allow you to create the table on the fly based on the results of the query:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'CREATE TABLE member AS SELECT user_id, ', 
     @sql, 
    ' FROM wpdg_usermeta GROUP BY user_id'
);
```

Note that the datatypes of the new table are inferred from the query's metadata; this might, or might no, to exactly what you want. You can check [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) for more detaiils.

Comment: That is excellent, thanks so much that seems to be doing the job