# MySQL concat with special characters

Tags: mysql, pivot, concatenation

From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12599372/1080742) of [question](http://MySQL%20pivot%20table%20query%20with%20dynamic%20columns) `MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns`

I modified(added new values) the query([demo 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=72f87eff117d68f143fa2262ddc13c3d)) in the `fieldname` with special characters like `-`, `(`, `)`. here's updated query [demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a8045d0c040dc44d5e58932e98903d5d) and got the syntax error

How do I write the correct syntax of `concat` with special characters from the [demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=a8045d0c040dc44d5e58932e98903d5d)?

Comment: Although my advice would be: do not do this.

Comment: I think this is not duplicate, my goal is to generating dynamic columns and trying to override the special characters from the generated pivot columns names. NOT adding new column names with special character in the table to database.

Comment: Column names are column names - it does not matter if you are creating them dynamically as aliases in a select query or you add them to a table. Same rules apply. You really should try the solution suggested to the duplicate question.

Comment: ok I already tried the backticks ``` in the `fieldname` but no success .please kindly [check](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b61fba4aed2f1892c4dd5cb1f4c24345)