# MYSQL Transpose the rows of the result of a select in column (Only 1 column result)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want transpose the result of this request in column

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name IN ('volumestest');
```

The result is this

| T0 |
| --- |
| T1 |
| T2 |
| T3 |
| T4 |
| T5 |
| T6 |

I WANT this

```
|T0|T1|T2|T3|T4|T5|T6|
```

I would like do this with options in the select if its possible and not with a variable storage.

Thanks u

Comment: You want the result in 7 columns or just one, comma-delimited column?

Comment: I have 113 rows when I do this command, and i want thoses rows in columns, just a transposition. So yes i want them in column, 1 value column for 1 value row. I want a dynamic transposition because the number of columns will change sometimes.

Comment: This topic can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql. Thenumber of columns must be static.

Comment: yes i saw it the problem is that the number of columns is not static

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns

Comment: The question Tohm linked has a solution for dynamic columns too, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26297463), or maybe have a look at [MySQL pivot table query with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12598120)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a dynamic statement and **PREPARE STATEMENT**
like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT("SELECT "
        , GROUP_CONCAT( column_name ) 
        , " FROM MYTABLE"
        , " WHERE 1=1") into @myQuery
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'
 AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'textil';

SELECT @myQuery;

PREPARE stmt FROM @MYQUERY;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [textil]> SELECT * from MYTABLE;
+----+------+------+------+
| T0 | T1   | T2   | T3   |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    2 |    4 |    8 |
|  2 |    4 |    8 |   16 |
+----+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [textil]> SELECT CONCAT("SELECT "
    ->  , GROUP_CONCAT( column_name ) 
    ->  , " FROM MYTABLE"
    -> , " WHERE 1=1") into @myQuery
    -> FROM information_schema.columns 
    -> WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'
    -> AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'textil';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [textil]> 
MariaDB [textil]> SELECT @myQuery;
+-------------------------------------------+
| @myQuery                                  |
+-------------------------------------------+
| SELECT T0,T1,T2,T3 FROM MYTABLE WHERE 1=1 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [textil]> 
MariaDB [textil]> PREPARE stmt FROM @MYQUERY;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

MariaDB [textil]> EXECUTE stmt;
+----+------+------+------+
| T0 | T1   | T2   | T3   |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    2 |    4 |    8 |
|  2 |    4 |    8 |   16 |
+----+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [textil]> 
MariaDB [textil]> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [textil]>
```