# Set Column Alias From Current Select ( MariaDB / MySQL )

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My Original Data  :

```
id   | GRP_ID | VAL_1  | VAL_2   | VAL_3  |  TYPE
---------------------------------------------------
1    |   R2   |  B01   |         |        | COL_B
2    |   R2   |        |   A01   |        | COL_A
3    |   R3   |  B02   |         |        | COL_B
4    |   R1   |        |   C01   |        | COL_C
5    |   R2   |  C02   |         |        | COL_C
6    |   R3   |        |         |   C03  | COL_C
```

Then i modified like this :

```
-----------------------------------------
GRP_ID  | group_CONCAT1      | group_CONCAT2         
-------------------------------------------
 R1     |  COL_C             | C01
 R2     |  COL_A,COL_B,COL_C | A01,B01,C02
 R3     |  COL_B,COL_C       | B02,C03
```

And i want get result like this :

```
GRP_ID  |COL_A  |  COL_B   | COL_C
----------------------------------
 R1     | ---   |   ---    | C01
 R2     | A01   |   B01    | C02
 R3     | ---   |   B02    | C03
```

Comment: What's the logic for deciding that the column order in the output is a,b,c? Are you imposing an alpha sort or is it simply the order of the longest group_concat1 in source? (which may or may not be ordered -you don't say). Also would it not be easier to go to source and skip the group_concats which force you to split strings?

Comment: What's your problem

Comment: Why is `A01`, `B01` and `C02` in the same line? Please post the query you use to get the `GROUP_CONCAT` results.

Comment: @p.salmon the result column name is not ordered just from split string

Comment: @FanoFN cause it have same sub_id on key of group by

Comment: There's no `sub_id` column mentioned in your data example above. I suggest you check with the [linked duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns) and see if any answer there solves your issue. If not, please update your question with more details - include `sub_id` that you mentioned and the query you've used to get the `GROUP_CONCAT()` results. Then we'll see if it really is a different issue, we'll vote to reopen your question.