# mysql display score along with friends of the current user

Tags: mysql, dynamic, pivot-table

I have 2 tables showing list of friends and list of score of each user.

```
 Table friends 
+-----------------+------------------+
|   user_id       |  friend_user_id  |  
+-----------------+------------------+
|   1             |     53           |
|   1             |     59           |
|   1             |     114          |
|   3             |     8            |
|   3             |     53           |
|   3             |     235          |
|   7             |     9            |
|   8             |     3            |
|   8             |     82           | 
+-----------------+------------------+


 Table score
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|   user_id       |  meta_key        |  meta_value      |
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|   1             |     math         |     70           |
|   1             |     science      |     80           |
|   3             |     math         |     99           |
|   3             |     science      |     99           |
|   7             |     math         |     0            |
|   7             |     science      |     55           |
|   8             |     math         |     50           |
|   8             |     science      |     66           |
|   9             |     math         |     99           |
|   9             |     science      |     99           |
|   53            |     math         |     12           |
|   53            |     science      |     12           |
|   59            |     math         |     66           |
|   59            |     science      |     97           |
|   82            |     math         |     89           |
|   82            |     science      |     44           |
|   114           |     math         |     99           |
|   114           |     science      |     95           |
|   235           |     math         |     32           |
|   235           |     science      |     88           |
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Query result should be dynamic enough and it must use 'current_logged_in_user_id'. I have a placeholder like '%CURRENT_USER_ID%' in the system.

so if a user_id =1 logged in to see the query result then, it should look like this, display his resutl along with his friends' score as below.

```
Expected result 
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|   subject       |  user_id1        | friend_user_id53 | friend_user_id59 |friend_user_id114 |
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|   math          |     70           |     12           |     66           |     99           |
|   science       |     80           |     12           |     97           |     95           | 
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

from user_id = 7 perspective

```
Expected result 
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|   subject       |  user_id7        | friend_user_id9  | 
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|   math          |     0            |     99           |
|   science       |     55           |     99           |
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I already can make it like below

```
Table 'I can query this'
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|   user_id       |    math          |  science         |
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|   1             |     70           |     80           |
|   3             |     99           |     99           |
|   7             |     0            |     55           |
|   8             |     50           |     66           |
|   9             |     99           |     99           |
|   53            |     12           |     12           |
|   59            |     66           |     97           |
|   82            |     89           |     44           |
|   114           |     99           |     95           |
|   235           |     32           |     88           |
+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

but to achieve the way of 'Expected result' above, it's beyond my knowledge.. so please help

Thank you!

Comment: You wouldn't do that with SQL, because "expected result" has a variable number of columns.

Comment: try this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: You can't discover the number of friends and also do a pivot table for all the user's friends _in a single query_, because the number of columns depends on the number of friends, but the columns of the query must be fixed _before_ the query begins reading data. So in general, you can't do a pivot-table as a single query. You have to either know the list of friends, or else do a preceding query to discover the list of friends. Then you can format the pivot-table query.

Comment: this might sound ridiculous but is it possible to transpose the table of 'I can query this' to achive the goal somehow?

Comment: @BillKarwin Any sample of preceding query that you are referring to? 
and we can get the list of friends from the sub-query though no?

Comment: @TimRoberts what if I set the max number of columns as 3? regardless how many friends a user has, the query limits 3 friends. then it can be done? if a user has less than 3 friends, then 2nd and 3rd column shows null.. possible?

Comment: In your example, `select friend_user_id from friends where user_id = 7` is a query that returns the list of friends of that user. Then write code to format the result set into a series of expressions to use in the subsequent pivot table query. Look at the examples in the linked question, or any of the many other question tagged with [mysql and pivot-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+pivot-table).

Comment: You cannot use a subquery to make a dynamic number of columns _in that same query_.